# Upload and replace file in given folder on Google Docs using .net api

Tags: .net, google-docs

I'm trying to upload a file to a given folder using the .net client for google-api. I can do this using:

```
service = new DocumentsService("SRDUploader");
DocumentEntry lastUploadEntry = service.UploadDocument(file, null );
```

That works fine, but I need to more things:

1. How can I specifying the destination folder (tried with "\My folder\file.txt" as secound arg)?
2. How can I specify that I wan't to overwrite the existing file?

I'm using [version 2](http://code.google.com/intl/no-NO/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html) version of the .net client api. Maybe there's another version?

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DocumentEntry parent = ....;
DocumentEntry deleting = ....;

deleting.Delete();

string feed = string.Format(DocumentsListQuery.foldersUriTemplate, parent.ResourceId);
// http://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/{0}/contents

var result = service.Insert(new Uri(feed), fileStream, fileExtension, fileName);
```