# Uploading document to Google Docs: how to replace existing and how to upload and convert large doc?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-docs

I am trying to make tool for backup/restore of Documents from Google account.
Backup is easy and I have no problems with it. But I have two unsolved questions for restore:

1) Is it possible to upload new version of existing document? When I upload document, it appears as separate copy.

I found it was discussed already here [Upload and replace file in given folder on Google Docs using .net api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780743/upload-and-replace-file-in-given-folder-on-google-docs-using-net-api), but it seems it was suggested just to remove old version before uploading new, the Id of document will be changed. Is this correct?

2) Google Docs have limit for size of documents able to be converted into internal format. http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37603. So it is possible to create large document, save it to local computer and then Google Docs will refuse to convert it because the document's size is over limit. In such case it is possible to upload the document without convert, but it becomes un-editable via web site. Is there some workaround for this situation?

[Unable to upload large files to Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839228/unable-to-upload-large-files-to-google-docs) - Here is advice to break document into small pieces before uploading and link them together after. But maybe there some other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**1. Is it possible to upload new version of existing document? When I upload document, it appears as separate copy.**

Yes, this is possible.  We call it "upload & replace" as you've noticed.  No need to remove the existing version first.  The following link describes how to do this in the protocol:

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UpdatingMetadataAndContent

From the .NET client library, what you need to do is attach a an input stream to the Update() request.  The method header for what you need is here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/src/core/service.cs#554

Create a stream containing your new file content, and just pass that in.  That should be it!

**2. Google Docs have limit for size... Is there some workaround for this situation?**

Unfortunately there is not a way currently to circumvent the size limitations of converted documents.  They must be uploaded as unconverted files, and thus, are not editable in the Google Docs user interface.